# nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "ssl" directive in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:70

Tags: ssl, nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm getting the following error when attempting to start my nginx server. I was able to configure the server to listen on port 80, and proxy to another address, but now I'm trying to configure it so the server listens on 443 with a cert assigned to it.

```
nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "ssl" directive in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:70
```

Here's my nginx.conf file

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        #ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        #ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##
        server {
        listen          443 ssl;
        server_name     localhost;


        ssl certificate         /etc/nginx/keys/example.com.pem;
        ssl certificate_key     /etc/nginx/keys/example.com.key;

        location / {
                 proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80;
        }
}

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        #include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Any ideas? I received the cert from Cloudflare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be have underscore ssl_:

```
 ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/keys/example.com.pem;
 ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/keys/example.com.key;
```